# How to jump between the two frames with keyshort when compare current file with history content?

Tags: intellij-idea, shortcut

In IDEA, when I edit the content of a file, I can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to show the comparation window. It splits into two frames, and the cursor is in the left frame by default.

I wonder how to jump to right frame by keyshort? For now, I can only do it by mouse.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> (Switcher) works for me on OS X.

Comment: Works for me on Linux too (gnome).